Python **kargs Нужен фильтр аргументов
Неизвестно, какие аргументы придут, поэтому надо написать фильтрующее условие, что-то типа такого:
def func(**kargs):
    if x in kargs.keys():   # NameError: name 'x' is not defined
        print(kargs[x])

func(n=4, x='aaa', a=22)


for x in kargs.keys(): ?

def func(**kargs):
for i in kargs.keys():
if i == x:
print(kargs[x])

нет, разумеется

Не могу понять суть вопроса. На вход функции передаётся неопределённый набор аргументов, вы хотите проитерироваться и отфильтровать которые вы заранее не определили функцией?

просто x сейчас не определён и вы пытаетесь сказать интерпретатору "возьми что-то, чего я не знаю (x) и проверь есть ли он в keys у kargs"

И все-таки, канонически называть kwargs, а не kargs

Нужно x заключить в кавычки:
def func(**kwargs):
    if 'x' in kwargs.keys():
        print(kwargs['x'])

func(n=4, x='aaa', a=22)

Когда Вы передаете в функцию аргументы через x='aaa', то x рассматривается как string (как и другие ключи словаря n, a). Документации не нашел, но есть обсуждение здесь.
Через заключение в кавычки Вы корректно обращаетесь по ключу словаря. Иначе (без '') функция пытается найти переменную x, которая не определена.

Интересное решение, работает. Но для нескольких аргументов надо каждый раз через if, т.е. elif не работает, это не хорошо. Но ок, спасибо!

А, x это у вас имя аргумента. Вам нужно определить массив известных аргументов knownArgs = ['x', 'n'] затем итерироваться в цикле for argName in knownArgs и затем проверять этот аргумент в kwargs: if argName in kwargs.keys()
